# Como criar abas numa aplicação android ?

Tags: android

```
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="Tipo:"/>
                <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/tipos">
                    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rodizio"
                        android:text="Rodízio"/>
                    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/fast_food"
                        android:text="Fast Food"/>
                    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/a_domicilio"
                        android:text="A Domicílio"/>
                </RadioGroup>
            </TableRow>
            <Button android:id="@+id/salvar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Salvar"/>
        </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não utilizes table rows, utiliza antes fragments com tabs:

> ### [Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)
>
> Swipe views provide lateral navigation between sibling screens such as tabs with a horizontal finger gesture (a pattern sometimes known as horizontal paging). This lesson teaches you how to create a tab layout with swipe views for switching between tabs, or how to show a title strip instead of tabs.